# How to test AD client on linux?

Tags: linux, active-directory

I am developing a web application that needs to authenticate against an Active Directory Domain Controller.

Currently I have no access to a Domain Controller, and the customer will only provide access later on in the development process. I need to have the integration ready by then.

What options do I have in order to run my own domain controller and perform some tests? I have thought of the following:

- Samba as AD
- run a "real" AD server on the cloud
- ???

I have no idea how easy is to set up each of those options, and how similar to the real thing this will be.

Can you provide some advice?

Comment: Running an Evaluation version of Windows Server in a VM?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can install [OpenLDAP](http://www.openldap.org/) or [ApacheDS](http://directory.apache.org/apacheds/) on your linux server, if it has not been already installed. Follow the links to get information on how to setup etc. This should not be too difficult. But will offer you the best flexibility in your testing.

Comment: Thanks, I can not upvote you because of low rep. If you upvote my question, I will slowly but surely get the rep enough to upvote answers. Thanks!

Comment: Ok. If it solves your problem, then tick it as accepted answer.